How do I print in portrait orientation on a 4 x 2 label?
I am designing a 4 x 2 label in SSRS and I need it to print like this:
Correct Orientation
However I cannot get SSRS to do this.
The labels on the printer are 4 inches wide x 2 inches high.
In the printer properties I have the default page setup set to 4 inches x 2 inches with portrait orientation.
In Visual Studio 2022 (Community Edition) I have set the report InteractiveSize and PageSize both to a width of 4 inches and a height of 2 inches.
When I print from SSRS the printer driver settings reflect the defaults I have set: Page size of 4 inches wide by 2 inches high in portrait orientation.
However when I right-click on the print preview in SSRS the page size is set to User and the orientation is set to Landscape. And when I print the text is rotated 90 degrees and printed over two labels.
If I right-click on the print preview and change the page size to 4 inches wide by 2 inches high and the orientation to Portrait then the label prints correctly.
However, if I save the label at this point, close Visual Studio, and re-open then the settings revert to User and Landscape and the label once again rotates.
I need to get SSRS to correctly pick up the defaults from the printer settings but I cannot for the life of me find a way.
I also tried the solution found at text (setting the report size to 4 x 4). Although this solves the rotation issue, it always prints 2 - 4 x 2 tags. One with the desired content and one blank.
Has anyone out there found a solution to this type of issue?

That sounds like you want Landscape orientation, not portrait.

You would think so, but the printer driver states regarding orientation that: Portrait prints images so that the bottom of the image comes out of the printer first. And this is what I need. Choosing landscape in the driver rotates the image so that the left edge of the image comes out first and the image is printed over two labels.

It turns out that I now have a solution: I have set up the page in Reporting Services to 4 x 2 (which defaults the orientation to landscape). Then I set the default page setup in the driver to 4 x 2 (Portrait). Manually printing at this stage prints the label rotated 90 degrees (over two labels). However, I was just made aware of an undocumented parameter available in our production software which will force the print action to be either landscape or portrait. Setting this parameter to portrait has solved the rotation issue and the label is now printing correctly. Thanks to all!
